# Deploying rails application. Getting 500 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

Trying to deploy my rails application but when access through web
I'm getting 500 error saying that

```
     The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner::Error
```

I googled the whole internet but found only couple of guys who had the same problem. One of them had it related to improper installation of facebooker gem, but I don't even have it.

Any ideas? I've been struggling with it past hours

I'm using

ruby 1.9.1p378
passenger-2.2.15 + nginx

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
fastthread (1.0.7)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)

Comment: Are you using passenger on apache or nginx? Post your nginx or apache config here.

Comment: Have you checked your Rails log file (`log/production.log`)?

Comment: Do you get this error when running it in development? What ruby version are you using in dev?

Comment: 1. passenger on nginx
server {
      listen 3333;
      server_name localhost;
      root html/elections/current/public;   
      passenger_enabled on;
   }
2. log/production.log is empty
3. no errors at all in development. ruby version is 1.8.7 here, I'm trying to downgrade ruby version on production server now

Comment: downgrading to ruby 1.8.7 didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. It looks like I just forgot to do rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load on deployment server.